# PHP MD5 Performance = is it processor hungry?

Tags: php, md5

md5() is usually for passwords, short strings

but this time I wanted to encrypt (w/o needing to decrypt) a large string, like a whole article ... (not to mention i'd be needing to do this every few seconds)

Would this be a problem? or would it take processor more work/longer to md5 a big string vs a short password?

I read md5 is really really fast..

For those curious, I'm trying to generate a "signature" of the string in question

Comment: no, md5 is not cpu intensive. that's why it's a useless choice for password hashing these days. it was DESIGNED to be fast/lightweight. but yes, md5's operation time is directly proportional to the size of the inputs.

Answer (score 9):

Oh dear.

1. Well, MD5 is *not* [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption).
   (Encryption is, by definition, designed to be reversible.)
2. Do *not* use MD5 or SHA for password hashes - they are *too* fast!
   (And MD5 is plain broken for such a task.)

Hash algorithms (including MD5) take time proportional to the size of the input, or O(n). That means, it will take about "twice as long" to hash 100MB as it does to hash 50MB. For in-memory PHP strings this will be "in the blink of an eye" (as the I/O will most likely be the bottleneck) - you'll need to *run performance benchmarks* on real data in a real environment to quantify it.

MD5 is indeed "really really fast"; the algorithm is relatively simple and, like many hash algorithms, was *designed* to be fast. Don't worry about performance until there is a *real* performance issue - modern CPUs are *very* fast. Also, while MD5 (and SHA) is fast, running MD5 back-to-back-to-back as in an infinite loop will of course "eat" all the CPU; an idle CPU is a wasted CPU if there is work to be done.

However, consider [SHA (preferable SHA-2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) for a "general" signature hashing - it is only marginally slower (by a constant factor) but it is a better algorithm, even when trimmed to the same output space, and just might prevent issues in the future.

Comment: thanks for your inputs.. just for fun debate, i believe mD5 is encryption as well by standard definition.. it's commonly referred to as one way encryption also. :P ... on a more serious note, could you elaborate on your POINT # 2? I don't quite understand what you're getting at on this one. ... and ok so i'm using Md5 for now.. it's just a few kb of data anyway (max 200kb on rare occassions).

Comment: @BrownChiLD No. It's not a debate, not even a fun one. ["encryption is the process of encoding messages (or information) in such a way that only authorized parties can *read [the original message\]*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). However, a hash (over all inputs) is neither a [injective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) nor a reversible function and thus *is not* encryption.

Comment: @BrownChiLD As for point #2, there are *plenty* of resources out there that [explain why MD5/SHA are *terrible choices* for *password* hashes](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/): "Even a “good” hashing scheme of `SHA2256(salt ∥ password)` *is still completely vulnerable to these cheap and effective attacks*, thus the importance of an adaptive hashing algorithm like bcrypt." (Note that article is 4 years old - computers/GPUs have only become *much faster* since then.)

Comment: @BrownChiLD tl;dr: I recommend using SHA for general (not password) signature hashing needs.

Comment: re the debate, haha ok.. fine you win :) .. about the rest of the advises, thanks very much.. it was insightful .. and while there is truth t md5/sha not being that good w/ password hashes, that all depends on what level of security you're gunning for.. for me, personally, i've never found the reason to toughen my password hashes because let's face it, it may not be bulletproof but it's pretty much enough. there will always be something more secure.... i believe that implementation is key.

Comment: @BrownChiLD It's secure and follows good security practices - or it is not. There is no "for me, personally" nonsense involved with such design choices.